# Convex hull of points

Tags: convex-optimization, polytopes

We're studying a course and we're dabbling a bit in convex optimization.
We were told that the convex hull of a set of points `x1,..,xn` is a polytope and we were asked to show that any face of the convex hull must contain at least one of these points.

We defined a face to be the intersection of the polytope with a supporting hyperplane. So according to the definitions in this course the empty set is not considered a face.

I also understand that a subset of `x1,..,xn` must be the vertices but we aren't meant to use this property. any suggestions on how to go about proving this?

Comment: What's your definition of supporting hyperplane? Depending, I'd start by proving that the polytope is a closed set.

Comment: We defined a supporting hyperplane to be any hyperplane (i.e all points x that solve <a,x> = b where <.,.> is the L2 inner product) which has a non-empty intersection with the polytope (denote the polytope as P). And for every point x in P <a,x> <= b

Comment: OK, that's really non-standard. I'm not sure what your question is asking in that case.

Comment: Well if a point x is contained both in P and in the supporting hyperplane H.
then X can be written as a convex combination of x1..xn
i.e X = Sum(ai * xi) where Sum(ai) = 1 and for all i ai >= 0 
on the other hand X is part of the hyperplane H so it solves the equation <a,X> = b

I guess that's all I have to work with

Comment: Sorry I misread your first comment. That is a standard definition. However I don't understand what you are trying to prove. Your first paragraph indicates that you're trying to prove that any face must contain at least one point, in other words, that it's non-empty. If a face is by definition the intersection of a supporting hyperplane with the polytope, and by definition the intersection of a supporting hyperplane with the polytope must be non-empty, then trivially a face is non-empty, as you seem to point out in the second paragraph.

Comment: Sorry I just realized I wrote the definition of the problem wrong. What I meant to write (and I added in an edit) is that I need to show that the face contains one of the points that are part of the convex hull's defining points (as in either one of x1..xn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an intuition-jogger, so if at any point reading this you get the picture of the proof, feel free to finish it yourself. Every point is a convex combination of your vertices. So take an arbitrary point in a given face and write it as such. Visualise if you have to, to make a conjecture about some vertices of the convex hull having to be in the face. As you've written, a supporting hyperplane corresponding to this face is defined in terms of the inner product: for some $a$ in your vector space and $b\in\mathbb{R}$, it is the set of all points $x$ with $\langle a,x\rangle=b$. Substitute your point in the face into this expression. Use the linearity properties of the inner product in such a way that they play nicely with the convex combination. Use the fact that for all points $p$ in the convex hull $\langle a,p\rangle\leq b$ to check your conjecture.